# Not showing data type for Swagger 3.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I have specify the data type for my id in my swagger editor which integer but it won't show it in the localhost server. Is it 3.0 problem? Because 2.0 seems to be showing!

[image: Here is a screenshot!]

```
'/pets/{id}':
    get:
      description: >-
        Returns a user based on a single ID, if the user does not have access to
        the pet
      operationId: find pet by id
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: ID of pet to fetch
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: pet response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
```

Comment: Can you post your spec json?

Comment: Here it is! Sorry about that!

Comment: Which UI renderer do you use?

Comment: Editor Swagger 3.0